# Apply Left Join in Laravel eloquent.

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following sql query-

```
SELECT 
   viewtasksactivitiesprojects.task_name, 
   users.firstname, 
   users.lastname 
FROM 
   viewtasksactivitiesprojects 
LEFT JOIN users 
   ON (viewtasksactivitiesprojects.activitytask_owner_id=users.id) 
WHERE 
   activitytasks_active=1 
   AND activity_status=5 
   AND activitytask_id IN
   (
      SELECT 
         activitytask_id 
      FROM 
         Activitytasks 
      WHERE 
         activity_id=26 AND active=1 
         AND task_status=8
   )
```

I m using Laravel framework in which I want to transform this query to laravel eloquent format.
However I have achieved the same at some extent but I am not able to implement the 'Join' Part of the query.
Can Anyone please suggest me how to implement the Left join in laravel eloquent. 
And one more thing is there any method in laravel by which we can pass the queries in sql format directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer-

```
DB::table('viewtasksactivitiesprojects')->leftJoin('Users',function($join){
           $join->on('viewtasksactivitiesprojects.activitytask_owner_id','=','users.id');
       })->whereIn('activitytask_id',function($query) use($id) {
                    $query->select('activitytask_id')
                            ->from(with(new Activitytask)->getTable())
                            ->where('activity_id', '=', $id)->where('active','=',1)->where('task_status','=',8);
                })->where('activitytasks_active','=',1)->where('activity_status','=',5)->get(array('viewtasksactivitiesprojects.task_name','users.firstname', 'users.lastname','users.id'));
```

Comment: mark your answer as the answer so it doesn't show as an unanswered question.